# how to combine import statements in python

Tags: python

As an example, here are my import statements:

```
from src.eb_environments.performance_reports.reports_procs.sp.all_targets import (
    add_sp_targets_to_db,
)
from src.eb_environments.performance_reports.reports_procs.sp.search_terms import (
    add_sp_sts_to_db,
)
from src.eb_environments.performance_reports.reports_procs.sb.keywords import (
    add_sb_kws_to_db,
)
from src.eb_environments.performance_reports.reports_procs.sb.targets import (
    add_sb_targets_to_db,
)
from src.eb_environments.performance_reports.reports_procs.sb.search_terms import (
    add_sb_st_to_db,
)
from src.eb_environments.performance_reports.reports_procs.sd.targets import (
    add_sd_targets_to_db,
)

directory structure:
-main.py  (where these import statement are located)
-src
   -eb_environments
      -performance_reports
         -reports_procs
            -sp
               -all_targets
                  -add_sp_targets_to_db.py
```

Since all of these lines share the same dir path down to 'reports_procs', then I thought that there would be a way to condense a section like this.

This module is located in the root dir of the project, so I don't believe using dot notation would have any benefit ie. src is in the same dir as this module.

I read about creating an **init**.py module that had all the imports in it in the 'reports_procs' dir but I was unable to get this to work.

Are there any ways to condense import sections like this?

FWIW, the parentheses are from the auto-formatter.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can import till common namespace and use namespace.func/class name. Like

```py
from src.eb_environments.performance_reports import reports_procs
```

And use the relevant funcs/classes like

```
report_procs.sp.all_targets.add_sp_targets_to_db() # or however to use it.
```

Also if these are in the same directory as the runner file, you can simply do

```
import reports_procs
```

To do this in `__init__` file, you need to create an `__init__.py` file in the module directory, and these import statements there.

Comment: thanks! - is it normal for the Pylance linter to not recognize this?

Comment: Yes, normally we do it like how you asked it in the question.

Comment: its not working. I am doing this and it is gving an error of: module 'src.eb_environments.performance_reports.reports_procs' has no attribute 'sp'

Comment: Can you add your directory structure in the question https://askubuntu.com/questions/431251/how-to-print-the-directory-tree-in-terminal